# enable button using javascript not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, magento-1.9

I am using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    function load() {
        var abc= document.getElementById('review_button');
        abc.disabled = false; 
        //alert("load event detected!");
    }
    window.onload = load;
</script>
```

This code is working well in firefox and IE but not working in chrome , even show alert on page load but when i click on button it again disabled that button that was enabled on page load.

Any suggestion must be appreciated..

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please insert the code in the question!

Comment: click on link you get code

Comment: Its an image of the code, thus I cannot: copy, edit, fix, extend, help.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
 function load() {
 var abc= document.getElementById('review_button');
 abc.disabled = false;
        //alert("load event detected!");
      }
      window.onload = load;
</script>

Answer (score 0):

//instead of this used for chrom

```
document.getElementById('review_button').disabled = false;
```

Comment: yes i even did this first but no success so i use variable

Comment: Dear it working in my chrom browser it may be happen some other issues

Answer (score 0):

The code you linked works fine on chrome:

https://jsfiddle.net/fm86t8ws/

```
<button id="review_button" disabled="true">
aaa
</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function load(){
var abc = document.getElementById('review_button');
abc.disabled = false;
}
window.onload = load;
</script>
```

This piece of code is most likely not the problem.

Comment: actually, this button is default disabled and i enable this using the above code and moreover this button is enable when page loads after that when i click on it, it disables again but in firefox or in IE this isn't happens